# Does FG Joomla to wordpress plugin import static pages such as About us, Services?

Tags: wordpress, joomla, migration

I have been trying to migrate my website from joomla to wordpress using the FG Joomla to wordpress plugin. It only migrate post, categories and media only. Does it also import static pages e.g home, about or services page. I have played around with the behavior settings nothing seems to work. Anyone with ideas on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi - welcome to the CiviCRM SE.  You don't mention CiviCRM - are you using it?  If so, you'll need to look at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switching-cms/switch-cms/  It does not cover Joomla to WP but will give you clues about what you need to do.   And if you're not using CiviCRM - this is the wrong SE for your question!

Answer (score 0):

If the pages are managed by native Joomla, they will be imported by the plugin. If they are managed by a third-party plugin, you may need an add-on to import them.
You should contact the support team at https://www.fredericgilles.net/support/